# var.replace is not a function

Tags: javascript

I'm using the below code to try to trim the string in Javascript but am getting the error mentioned in the title:

```
function trim(str) {
    return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
}
```

**Edit:**

I fixed the problem.... sorry I should have put the code on how I was calling it too.... realized I accidentally was passing the object of the form field itself rather than its value.

Comment: `str` is probably not a string

Comment: As an aside: you're missing quotes around the `regex` string itself, which mightn't be good anyway.

Comment: @MrDisappointment Javascript has literal regular expressions - they don't need to be a string

Comment: @Gareth: Ahhh, cool, ...I guess, ...maybe (?)

Comment: @Closure: You may find (or wish to start) a discussion at http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=contractions

Comment: @patrick dw: +1 for that suggestion. @Gareth: lol@Epic; I like it.

Comment: @ClosureCowboy: It's English. It's short for "might not".

Comment: Use `str.toString().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'')` instead.

Answer (score 337, accepted):

My guess is that the code that's calling your `trim` function is *not* actually passing a string to it.

To fix this, you can make `str` a string, like this: `str.toString().replace(...)`
<sub>...as [alper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2402577/alper) pointed out below.</sub>

Comment: `str.toString()` fixed my problem.

Comment: Well, `str.toString()` is only the solution if you are passing a correct value that can successfully be converted _to_ a string; in my case I was passing the wrong thing altogether. :)

Comment: I also getting same error, I tried toString() but getting error: cannot read property "toString" is undefined and same for "replace"

Comment: Great guess! Turned out to be exactly what I was missing. Worked great by adding in `.toString()`.

Comment: Work's for me. i added toString().replace(....) and works.

Answer (score 102):

## probable issues:

- variable is **NUMBER** (instead of string);

  `num=35;    num.replace(3,'three');                =====> ERROR`

  `num=35;    num.toString().replace(3,'three');     =====> CORRECT !!!!!!`

  `num='35';  num.replace(3,'three');                =====> CORRECT !!!!!!`
- variable is **object** (instead of string);
- variable is not defined;

Comment: Thanks For this, I was facing an issue, Where, I was getting String in an typeof object. I converted that object with toString(). And It is working! Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

> Replace wouldn't replace numbers. It replaces strings only.

This should work.

```
function trim(str) {
    return str.toString().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
}
```

If you only want to trim the string. You can simply use **"str.trim()"**

Answer (score 6):

You are not passing a string otherwise it would have a `replace` method. I hope you didnt type `function trim(str) { return var.replace(blah); }` instead of `return str.replace`.

Answer (score 6):

You should probably do some validations before you actually execute your function :

```
function trim(str) {
    if(typeof str !== 'string') {
        throw new Error('only string parameter supported!');
    }

    return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Did you call your function properly? Ie. is the thing you pass as as a parameter really a string?

Otherwise, I don't see a problem with your code - the example below works as expected

```
function trim(str) {
    return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
}


trim('    hello   ');  // --> 'hello'
```

However, if you call your functoin with something non-string, you will indeed get the error above:

```
trim({});  // --> TypeError: str.replace is not a function
```

Answer (score 5):

In case of a number you can try to convert to string:

```
var stringValue = str.toString();
return stringValue.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use toString() Method of java script for the convert into string before because replace method is a string function.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem.... sorry I should have put the code on how I was calling it too.... realized I accidentally was passing the object of the form field itself rather than it's value.

Thanks for your responses anyway. :)

Comment: You can edit the question, that's better than giving an answer to yourself. Oh, and while you're at it, pick one of the nice people and accept their answer. :-)

Comment: @Christopher: No; if he solved it himself, he should write his answer and accept it. That's SO best practice. Putting solutions in questions and accepting arbitrary answers is not.

Comment: @Tomalak: There are several correct answers here, older than this one. I agree that accepting your own answer if it is the first correct one is a good thing™, and certainly did not want to suggest putting the solution into the question.

Comment: @Christopher: The accepted answer should be the one that contains the solution the OP used.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are passing string to "replace" method. Had same issue and solved it by passing string. You can also make it to string using toString() method.

Answer (score 0):

I just got this very same error. I thought I could trust on the function signature - since the string type is explicit in it. The code below reproduces this scenario and yes, the toString fixed the problem.

```
const REMOVE_MASK_RE = /[^\d]/g;
export function removeMask(value: string): string {
  return value.replace(REMOVE_MASK_RE, '');
}

describe('removeMask', () => {
  it('test #TypeError: value.replace is not a function', () => {
    expect(() => {
      expect(removeMask(123 as unknown as string)).toBeFalsy();
    }).toThrowError('value.replace is not a function');
  });
});
```