# Javascript: sorting arrays that contain dates into descending order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have the following array:

```
var times = [
            ["04/11/10", "86kg"], 
            ["05/12/11", "90kg"],
            ["06/12/11", "89kg"]
];
```

I want to list these dates and their corresponding weights in ascending order.

I know you can sort arrays with *sort* and I found the following function from [this About.com page](http://javascript.about.com/library/blsort3.htm) which I thought would do what I wanted:

```
times.sort(dmyOrdA);
var dateRE = /^(\d{2})[\/\-](\d{2})[\/\-](\d{2})/;
function dmyOrdA(a,b) {
    a = a.replace(dateRE, "$3$2$1");
    b = b.replace(dateRE, "$3$2$1");

    if (a > b) {
        return 1;
    }

    else if (a < b) {
        return -1;
    }

    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

However, using this function gives me the following error:

```
a.replace is not a function
```

Is anyone able to help with my query?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Looking at a previous [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775206/var-replace-is-not-a-function) it seems as if in my case 'a' is not a string. However, I don't understand why this is so.

Comment: Because your `times` array stores 3 arrays in your example, not strings (like `["04/11/10", "86kg"]`). So with the sorting function, `a` and `b` will be two arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when sorting an array, the parameters that the `sort` function takes are array elements.
In your case, you array elements are also arrays... bummer.
You want to sort the array of arrays by the first element of each element (tricky).
So just change the `a` and `b` to `a[0]` and `b[0]` :

```
function dmyOrdA(a,b) {
    a = a[0].replace(dateRE, "$3$2$1");
    b = b[0].replace(dateRE, "$3$2$1");
    if (a > b)
        return 1;
    else if (a < b)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

You got `a.replace is not a function` because replace is a `String` method and you tried to apply it to an `Array`

Comment: Great thanks Gion that works perfectly. To be honest the sort function completely baffles me. I'm passing 'a' and 'b' as parameters to the 'dmyOrdA' function but I can't see what relationship this has to my 'times' array. If you had time it would be great if you could explain this. Thanks.

Comment: @Stephen Young: When you sort an array in javascript, you need to provide a way of comparison between two of the array's elements.  This way, you pass as a  parameter to the sort method a function that takes 2 elements of your array and decides which one will be `lower` and which one will be `greater`.If the first element is `grater` than the other, the function will return `1`.If it is lower than the other, it will return `-1`, and if they're equal, it returns `0`. You can picture the function as a question: is the first element bigger than the second?Answer:`1`-yes,`-1`-no,`0`-inconclusive

Comment: @gion_13 I think I'm beginning to understand this. Just two questions: (1) You say "you pass as a parameter to the sort method a function that takes 2 elements of your array" but how does the sort method know how to sort _all_ the elements in the array? (2) I don't understand the `return` aspect of the function. If you take out the `else if` part and change `if (a > b) return 1` to `if (a > b) return -1` it will still sort by ascending order. However, if you leave out the `(a > b)` statement and just have `if (a < b) return -1` it will not sort by descending order but `return 1` will. Why?

Comment: (1)It depends on the browser implementation, but i think that the sort method applies the given function recursively on pairs of elements.In order to sort a list, you must-at a certain point- compare two elements;and your function tells the comparison logic.For sorting algorithms see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm.(2)If you change one if,change the other one too;) You must always have a return value for each comparison case, so that the algorithm would know how to alter the list. If you try something like `[4,3,2,1].sort(function(a,b){return -1;})`,you won't get a sorted list.

Comment: I'm nearly there now!! The Mozilla docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) says "If `compareFunction(a, b)` is greater than 0, sort `b` to a lower index than `a`." In that case if you do `if (a > b) return -1` then surely `a` should be sorted to a lower index than `b`? But if you do this nothing is sorted.

Comment: as i said before, if you change the return value for `a>b` you should change it for `a<b` as well. So `if (a > b) return -1` doesnt do anything, but `if (a > b) return -1 else if(a<b) return 1;return 0` does sort your array descending.

Comment: @gion_13 Ok thanks. And what if I wanted to sort my times array by the second elements so 90kg, 86kg etc? I thought removing the `replace` function and writing `a[0][0]` and `b[0][0]` would work but it doesn't.

Comment: @Stephen Young: It does work, that is if you put the right parameters.You should compare `a[1]` with `b[1]`, because `a` and `b` are elements of the array you want to sort, which are arrays themselves also.If you want to order them by their second element, you have to access their second element (aka: `el[1]`). If you use `a[0][0]` that value will be undefined, because `a` is a single-dimension array.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert to proper dates and then subtract in the compare function:

```
function dmyOrdA(a,b){return myDate(a[0]) - myDate(b[0]);}
function myDate(s){var a=s.split("/"); return new Date("20"+a[2],a[1]-1,a[0]);}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was wondering how to do that. Why do you put `-1` after `a[1]`?

Comment: The month parameter is 0 based; the day is 1 based