# trim is not a function error

Tags: javascript, mootools, trim

I recently get this error and not sure how to resolve it...

```
TypeError: $(...).get(...).trim is not a function
```

The script I use is this:

```
function vbstatus_change_status(statusID,userID,inputID,editboxID,statusboxID)
{
    $(inputID).value=vbstatus_htmlspecialchars_decode($(statusID).get('text').trim(),'ENT_QUOTES');
    $(statusboxID).setStyle('display','none');
    $(editboxID).setStyle('display','inline');
    $(inputID).addEvent('keydown',function(e){
        if(e.key=='enter'){
            vbstatus_update_status(statusID,userID,inputID,editboxID,statusboxID);
        }
    }); 
    if($chk($('inlinemodform'))){
        $('inlinemodform').addEvent('submit', vbstatus_formkill);
    }

}
```

I was looking at an issue similar to the one I have [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775206/var-replace-is-not-a-function), yet not sure how to deal with it!!

any idea how to do that?

**Update:** here the script I'm using

```
function vbstatus_htmlspecialchars_decode (string, quote_style) {

    var optTemp = 0, i = 0, noquotes= false;
    if (typeof quote_style === 'undefined') {        quote_style = 2;
    }
    string = string.toString().replace(/&lt;/g, '<').replace(/&gt;/g, '>');
    var OPTS = {
        'ENT_NOQUOTES': 0,        'ENT_HTML_QUOTE_SINGLE' : 1,
        'ENT_HTML_QUOTE_DOUBLE' : 2,
        'ENT_COMPAT': 2,
        'ENT_QUOTES': 3,
        'ENT_IGNORE' : 4    };
    if (quote_style === 0) {
        noquotes = true;
    }
    if (typeof quote_style !== 'number') { // Allow for a single string or an array of string flags        quote_style = [].concat(quote_style);
        for (i=0; i < quote_style.length; i++) {
            // Resolve string input to bitwise e.g. 'PATHINFO_EXTENSION' becomes 4
            if (OPTS[quote_style[i]] === 0) {
                noquotes = true;            }
            else if (OPTS[quote_style[i]]) {
                optTemp = optTemp | OPTS[quote_style[i]];
            }
        }        quote_style = optTemp;
    }
    if (quote_style & OPTS.ENT_HTML_QUOTE_SINGLE) {
        string = string.replace(/&#0*39;/g, "'"); // PHP doesn't currently escape if more than one 0, but it should
        // string = string.replace(/&apos;|&#x0*27;/g, "'"); 
// This would also be useful here, but not a part of PHP    
}
    if (!noquotes) {
        string = string.replace(/&quot;/g, '"');
    }

    return string;
}


function vbstatus_get_html_translation_table (table, quote_style) {

    var entities = {}, hash_map = {}, decimal = 0, symbol = '';    var constMappingTable = {}, constMappingQuoteStyle = {};
    var useTable = {}, useQuoteStyle = {};

    // Translate arguments
    constMappingTable[0]      = 'HTML_SPECIALCHARS';    constMappingTable[1]      = 'HTML_ENTITIES';
    constMappingQuoteStyle[0] = 'ENT_NOQUOTES';
    constMappingQuoteStyle[2] = 'ENT_COMPAT';
    constMappingQuoteStyle[3] = 'ENT_QUOTES';
     useTable       = !isNaN(table) ? constMappingTable[table] : table ? table.toUpperCase() : 'HTML_SPECIALCHARS';
    useQuoteStyle = !isNaN(quote_style) ? constMappingQuoteStyle[quote_style] : quote_style ? quote_style.toUpperCase() : 'ENT_COMPAT';

    if (useTable !== 'HTML_SPECIALCHARS' && useTable !== 'HTML_ENTITIES') {
        throw new Error("Table: "+useTable+' not supported');        // return false;
    }

    entities['38'] = '&amp;';
    if (useTable === 'HTML_ENTITIES') {        entities['160'] = '&nbsp;';
        entities['161'] = '&iexcl;';
        entities['162'] = '&cent;';
        entities['163'] = '&pound;';
        entities['164'] = '&curren;';        entities['165'] = '&yen;';
        entities['166'] = '&brvbar;';
        entities['167'] = '&sect;';
        entities['168'] = '&uml;';
        entities['169'] = '&copy;';        entities['170'] = '&ordf;';
        entities['171'] = '&laquo;';
        entities['172'] = '&not;';
        entities['173'] = '&shy;';
        entities['174'] = '&reg;';        entities['175'] = '&macr;';
        entities['176'] = '&deg;';
        entities['177'] = '&plusmn;';
        entities['178'] = '&sup2;';
        entities['179'] = '&sup3;';        entities['180'] = '&acute;';
        entities['181'] = '&micro;';
        entities['182'] = '&para;';
        entities['183'] = '&middot;';
        entities['184'] = '&cedil;';        entities['185'] = '&sup1;';
        entities['186'] = '&ordm;';
        entities['187'] = '&raquo;';
        entities['188'] = '&frac14;';
        entities['189'] = '&frac12;';        entities['190'] = '&frac34;';
        entities['191'] = '&iquest;';
        entities['192'] = '&Agrave;';
        entities['193'] = '&Aacute;';
        entities['194'] = '&Acirc;';        entities['195'] = '&Atilde;';
        entities['196'] = '&Auml;';
        entities['197'] = '&Aring;';
        entities['198'] = '&AElig;';
        entities['199'] = '&Ccedil;';        entities['200'] = '&Egrave;';
        entities['201'] = '&Eacute;';
        entities['202'] = '&Ecirc;';
        entities['203'] = '&Euml;';
        entities['204'] = '&Igrave;';        entities['205'] = '&Iacute;';
        entities['206'] = '&Icirc;';
        entities['207'] = '&Iuml;';
        entities['208'] = '&ETH;';
        entities['209'] = '&Ntilde;';        entities['210'] = '&Ograve;';
        entities['211'] = '&Oacute;';
        entities['212'] = '&Ocirc;';
        entities['213'] = '&Otilde;';
        entities['214'] = '&Ouml;';        entities['215'] = '&times;';
        entities['216'] = '&Oslash;';
        entities['217'] = '&Ugrave;';
        entities['218'] = '&Uacute;';
        entities['219'] = '&Ucirc;';        entities['220'] = '&Uuml;';
        entities['221'] = '&Yacute;';
        entities['222'] = '&THORN;';
        entities['223'] = '&szlig;';
        entities['224'] = '&agrave;';        entities['225'] = '&aacute;';
        entities['226'] = '&acirc;';
        entities['227'] = '&atilde;';
        entities['228'] = '&auml;';
        entities['229'] = '&aring;';        entities['230'] = '&aelig;';
        entities['231'] = '&ccedil;';
        entities['232'] = '&egrave;';
        entities['233'] = '&eacute;';
        entities['234'] = '&ecirc;';        entities['235'] = '&euml;';
        entities['236'] = '&igrave;';
        entities['237'] = '&iacute;';
        entities['238'] = '&icirc;';
        entities['239'] = '&iuml;';        entities['240'] = '&eth;';
        entities['241'] = '&ntilde;';
        entities['242'] = '&ograve;';
        entities['243'] = '&oacute;';
        entities['244'] = '&ocirc;';        entities['245'] = '&otilde;';
        entities['246'] = '&ouml;';
        entities['247'] = '&divide;';
        entities['248'] = '&oslash;';
        entities['249'] = '&ugrave;';        entities['250'] = '&uacute;';
        entities['251'] = '&ucirc;';
        entities['252'] = '&uuml;';
        entities['253'] = '&yacute;';
        entities['254'] = '&thorn;';        entities['255'] = '&yuml;';
    }

    if (useQuoteStyle !== 'ENT_NOQUOTES') {
        entities['34'] = '&quot;';    }
    if (useQuoteStyle === 'ENT_QUOTES') {
        entities['39'] = '&#39;';
    }
    entities['60'] = '&lt;';    entities['62'] = '&gt;';


    // ascii decimals to real symbols
    for (decimal in entities) {        symbol = String.fromCharCode(decimal);
        hash_map[symbol] = entities[decimal];
    }

    return hash_map;}
function vbstatus_htmlentities (string, quote_style) {
    var hash_map = {}, symbol = '', tmp_str = '', entity = '';
    tmp_str = string.toString();    
    if (false === (hash_map = vbstatus_get_html_translation_table('HTML_ENTITIES', quote_style))) {
        return false;
    }
    hash_map["'"] = '&#039;';    for (symbol in hash_map) {
        entity = hash_map[symbol];
        tmp_str = tmp_str.split(symbol).join(entity);
    }
        return tmp_str;
}
function vbstatus_formkill(e){
e.stop();
}
function vbstatus_change_status(statusID,userID,inputID,editboxID,statusboxID)
{
    $(inputID).value=vbstatus_htmlspecialchars_decode($(statusID).get('text').trim(),'ENT_QUOTES');
    $(statusboxID).setStyle('display','none');
    $(editboxID).setStyle('display','inline');
    $(inputID).addEvent('keydown',function(e){
        if(e.key=='enter'){
            vbstatus_update_status(statusID,userID,inputID,editboxID,statusboxID);
        }
    }); 
    if($chk($('inlinemodform'))){
        $('inlinemodform').addEvent('submit', vbstatus_formkill);
    }

}

function vbstatus_update_status(statusID,userID,inputID,editboxID,statusboxID)
{
    var update_url = 'vbstatus.php?do=update_status';
    var update_text = $(inputID).value;
    var req = new Request.HTML({url:update_url, data:{'status':update_text},
        onSuccess: function(html,responseElements,responseHTML,responseJavascript) {
            var myJSON = JSON.decode(responseHTML);
                $(statusID).set('html',myJSON.updated_status);
                $(statusboxID).setStyle('display','inline');
                $(editboxID).setStyle('display','none');
                if($chk($('inlinemodform'))){
                $('inlinemodform').removeEvent('submit', vbstatus_formkill);
                }

                $(inputID).removeEvents('keydown');
                    },
        onFailure: function() {
                $(statusID).set('text','The Request Failed');
                if($chk($('inlinemodform'))){
                $('inlinemodform').removeEvent('submit', vbstatus_formkill);    
                }
                $(inputID).removeEvents('keydown');
                    }
                });
    req.send();
}
```

**Update# 2:** this script uses mootools lib.

**Update # 3: is it possible to convert this script to Jquery instead of Mootools?**

Comment: do you use some library here?

Comment: yes, I use mootools.js lib

Comment: Are you sure to have loaded your own trim function before the peace of code using it ?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum you are right - I've edited my comment earlier. `trim` wasn't defined on old browsers and I use to support them - so I never use it in plain JS. though creating one in the string prototype object is super easy

Comment: My guess is that .get("text") is not returning a string

Comment: @basilikum as I said to Benjamin - this is not supported in old browsers (IE8-, FF3-) and setting it is very simple http://www.javascripter.net/faq/trim.htm

Comment: but this is happening on FF28

Comment: What do you get from: $(statusID).get('text') ?

Comment: I get the user status; what users write for their own through a vbulletin plugin

Comment: I mean, if you run that code by itself, what do you get? A string, object, array, undefined?

Comment: And you've tested that?

Comment: I did, but the only issue is that recently it doesn't work anymore. As updates are made for both vbulletin and internet browsers, it has stopped working!!

Comment: I think I made it work now!!! Thanks everyone for trying to help. I will post the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution myself, but Thanks a lot for everyone who tried to help. The answer was simple to what I thought.

All I had to do is changing the

> $(

To

> document.id(

I did that for all `$(` in the script

And the script started working again.

Comment: If this was the solution, then you had another library (probably jQuery) stealing the `$` from MooTools. You can do with MooTools everything jQuery does, so might be better to not mix too much. Anyway, using `document.id()` instead of `$` is smart and avoids this kind of problems.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid issues like that define self-invoking function and pass document.id as the argument:

```
(function($) {
    // in this context $ refers to the document.id
})(document.id);
```