# Uncaught TypeError. Item.replace is not a function, autoComplete plugin

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, autocomplete

I'm using jQuery plugin autoComplete https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/auto-complete/demo.html, and I'm trying to use their ajax request unfortunately I got an error.

It says the

> item.replace is not a function at object.renderItem

```
$.fn.autoComplete.defaults = {
    source: 0,
    minChars: 3,
    delay: 150,
    cache: 1,
    menuClass: '',
    renderItem: function (item, search){
        // escape special characters
        search = search.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
        var re = new RegExp("(" + search.split(' ').join('|') + ")", "gi");
        return '<div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-val="' + item + '">' + item.replace(re, "<b>$1</b>") + '</div>';
    },
    onSelect: function(e, term, item){}
};
```

Here is my code

```
$('.to_msg').autoComplete({
    source: function(term, response){
        $.getJSON('ajax/auto_complete_ajax.php', { q: term }, 
        function(data){ 
            response(data); 
        });
    }
});
```

And my PHP response

```
$recipient = $_GET['q'];
$a_json = array();
$a_json_row = array();


//restrict the store
$query_filter = $db->query("SELECT * from master_data.user_account where Name like '%$recipient%'");
while($result_filter = $query_filter->whileFetch()){
    $name = htmlentities(stripcslashes($result_filter['Name']));
    $user_id = htmlentities(stripcslashes($result_filter['user_id']));    
    $a_json_row['user_id'] = $user_id;
    $a_json_row['value'] = $name;
    $a_json_row['label'] = $name;
    array_push($a_json, $a_json_row);
}

echo json_encode($a_json);
flush();
```

Here is the JSON output

```
[
   {"user_id":"5","value":"Melde Feliciano   ","label":"Melde Feliciano   "},
   {"user_id":"46","value":"Melanie Charlton ","label":"Melanie Charlton "}
]
```

Comment: Your error is saying that `.replace` is not a function, are you looking for `str_replace()` ?

Comment: Oops, im mixing php with JS, my apologies its 2am lol :)

Comment: [var.replace is not a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775206/var-replace-is-not-a-function) Take a look at this question to see if it helps you!

Comment: What does 'data' equal in response(data)? Can you console.log it just before you call that function?

Answer (score 3):

`item` in `renderItem(item, search)` is an object. Try replacing `item.replace()` with `item.label.replace()`.

```
$.fn.autoComplete.defaults = {
    source: 0,
    minChars: 3,
    delay: 150,
    cache: 1,
    menuClass: '',
    renderItem: function (item, search){
        // escape special characters
        search = search.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
        var re = new RegExp("(" + search.split(' ').join('|') + ")", "gi");
        return '<div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-val="' + item.value + '">' + item.label.replace(re, "<b>$1</b>") + '</div>';
    },
    onSelect: function(e, term, item){}
};
```